# Leaflet artifact on GeoJSON hexgrid without borders at zoom 10

Tags: leaflet, geojson, hexagonal-grid

I'm having an issue on a Leaflet map with an hexgrid without border lines. At zoom level 10 and more, those blank artifacts appear.

[image]

You can see this web-map deployed here:

https://guillermodangelo.com/grid_stack_exchange/index.html

This is my code so far:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
 <title>Asthma danger map</title>
 <style>
   
   #map {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
   }

   nav {
   position: fixed;
   height: 35px;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   left: 0;
   background: #611f53;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 5px;
   }

   body  {
   position: fixed;
   top: 35px;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   left: 0;
   vertical-align: top;
   }

</style>
</head>

<body>
 <nav>
   <p style="color:white;">Asthma danger map</p>
 </nav>
 
 <div id="map"></div>

</body>

</html>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./data/hexgrid.js"></script>

<script>

 var Esri_WorldImagery = L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
   attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community'
 });

 var CartoDB_Positron = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
   attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
   subdomains: 'abcd',
   maxZoom: 19
 });
 

 const extent = [34, -118.22]

   var map = L.map('map', {
       center: extent,
       zoom: 10,
   preferCanvas: true,
       layers: CartoDB_Positron
   });


 function getColor(d) {
       return  d === 'HIGHEST' ? '#48194c' :
           d === 'HIGH'    ? '#8856a7' :
           d === 'LOWER'   ? '#8c96c6' :
           d === 'LOWEST'  ? '#b3cde3' :
                 '#8856a7';
   }

 
 function style(feature) {
   return {
       fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.danger_level),
       fillOpacity: 0.5,
       weight: 0,
   };
 }

 var grid = L.geoJson(hexgrid, {
   style: style,
 }).addTo(map);
 

L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);


</script>
```

The JS data is here: https://guillermodangelo.com/grid_stack_exchange/data/hexgrid.js

The grid was made in QGIS (EPSG:3857), reprojected in geopandas and then exported to GeoJSON with CRS ESPG:4326.
My hypothesis is that this reprojection generates tiny slivers of uncovered space, that is showed by leaflet at small zoom (10, 11 and so on).

I would like to hear your thoughts on this, and possible ways to fix this (a bigger cell grid?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like some kind of a bug. I didn't go into details why this happens, just found a workaround with modifying style.

Instead of stroke weight `0`, it gets weight `1`. Since polygons overlap, this gives undesired effect at borders if opacity is `0.5`. So opacity is set to one, but the whole GeoJSON layer opacity is set to `0.5` with the help of separate map pane.

So relevant code could look something like this (tested):

```
 function style(feature) {
   var color = getColor(feature.properties.danger_level);
   return {
     fillColor: color ,
     fillOpacity: 1,
     color: color,
     opacity: 1,
     weight: 1,
   };
 }

 map.createPane('myPane');
 map.getPane('myPane').style.opacity = 0.5;
 
 var grid = L.geoJson(hexgrid, {
   style: style,
   pane: 'myPane'
 }).addTo(map);
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks TomazicM! I really appreciate your help, your code snippetts helped me a lot, and I managed to fix this issue. Also, I learned about "map panes", which didn't had used before.